# "Illegal filter on FeedItem" error in soql query

Tags: soql

im trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT Id, Parent.RecordTypeId FROM FeedItem WHERE Type='EmailMessageEvent' AND Visibility!='AllUsers' AND Parent.Type = 'Case' AND Parent.RecordTypeId = '01258000000cZYOAA2'
```

I receive the error

> MALFORMED_QUERY - Illegal filter on FeedItem

anyone familiar with this error and how to overcome it?

in case it helps,
that's the code i use the query on:

```
global class EmailFeeditemBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable{

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
    RecordType rt = [SELECT ID FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'Support' AND SobjectType =  'Case' LIMIT 1]; //PUT THIS UP

    String  query = 'SELECT Id, Parent.RecordTypeId FROM FeedItem WHERE Type=\'EmailMessageEvent\' AND Visibility!=\'AllUsers\' AND Parent.Type = \'Case\' AND Parent.RecordTypeId = \''+rt.Id+'\'';
    System.debug(query);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}


global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<FeedItem> scope){

    List <FeedItem> feedItemToUpdateList = new List<FeedItem>();
    for(FeedItem feedItem_i : scope){
            feedItem_i.Visibility = 'AllUsers';  
            feedItemToUpdateList.add(feedItem_i);
    }
    if (feedItemToUpdateList.size()>0){
        update feedItemToUpdateList;    
    }
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

    database.executeBatch(new EmailFeeditemBatch(), 5);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't filter or Parent.RecordtypeId. I can't find any documentation for this but if I remove it the rest of the query works.

This leaves you with two possibilities. You can use a semi-join in you where clause to filter on the parents with the correct record type:

```
SELECT Id,    
       Parent.RecordTypeId 
FROM FeedItem 
WHERE Type='EmailMessageEvent' 
AND Visibility !='AllUsers' 
AND Parent.Type = 'Case' 
AND ParentId IN (SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId = '01258000000cZYOAA2')
```

You could also query all the FeedItems without filtering on the Parent.RecordtypeId, and than loop over them to select the right ones. However this is less efficient and I'd suggest you use the first solution.

Comment: Actually I think you should be able to use a join here. `ParentId IN (SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE RecordTypeId = '...')`

Comment: @Kasper i don't understand the first possibilty you mentioned, can you explain again\give an example code?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Good point, thank you. Dana, please give me one moment, I'll edit the code to include the query and Adrians feedback.